# Searching for some individuals in a biplot in R

Tags: r, pca

I'm working with biplot function to figure out some assumptions about certain individuals, the problem is that I have plenty of individuals and I can't find those I want to study. I've searched a lot and I have come to the conclusion that there is no way to, for example, change the colour of some individuals in a biplot. I have no idea, I have tried everything and nothing works. The only thing I want is to highlight in the biplot some individuals, I don't mind how.

I tried everything, with biplot, fivz_, adding geom_point, but didn't work.

I'm working with the USArrests data, and the individuals are South Carolina, Mississippi and North Carolina.

Comment: You'll get more help if you can provide a reproducible example, it's hard to assist when we don't have anything to work with.

Comment: Hi Toad, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks